# How to use print js in laravel by installing it through npm?

Tags: laravel, npm

I want to use print js in laravel and i want to install it through npm

`npm install print-js`

Is it possible to use it this way?
Is it possible to use it from node_modules?

Comment: Are you using Laravel with Vue or any framework ?

Comment: So you want to use a JS package in a PHP framework.

Comment: No I'm not using any frontend framework with Laravel.

Comment: Yes, I Want to use Js package in Laravel with npm.